# dynamically create a class in c#.net

Tags: c#

I want to dynamically create a class in c#.net.

I tried using anonymous methods since the number of member variables is given dynamically,
i tried like this,

```
string element = "element";
string str = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++)
{
    str = String.Concat(str, element + i, "=String.Empty", ",");
    if (i == elementsCount - 1)
        str = String.Concat(str, element + i, "=String.Empty");
}
string s = "new{" + str + "}";
var a=s;
```

and

i want to assign the class 'a' like ObservableCollection but i could not do this.

Is there any way to do these two??
but this is not the right way i guess;

Comment: "I want to dynamically create a class in c#.net." No you don't. Unless you know what the heck are you doing. Which obviously, you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try look here:

[Dynamic in C# 4.0: Introducing the ExpandoObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a very helpful idea to create a class on the fly, since none of your other code will be able to talk to it at compile time. What is the objective here? Options:

- use a `Dictionary<string,object>` to return data keyed by name
- in 4.0, use `ExpandoObject`, which has both dictionary and `dynamic` APIs
- if this is for databinding, implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and provide properties at runtime

For example:

```
    string element = "element";
    string str = String.Empty;
    int elementsCount = 20;
    IDictionary<string,object> obj = new ExpandoObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++)
    {
        obj[element + i] = "value " + i;
    }
    dynamic viaDynamic = obj;
    string val0 = viaDynamic.element0; // = "value 0"
```

but importantly, this still has the `IDictionary<string,object>` API for static use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to crate classes (types) or instances of existing types?

For the latter look at System.Reflection and the [activator class](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/activator_createinstance.html)

if you're using .net 4 you can use the DLR from c#

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Reflection for that, and here´s a handy tutorial:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Comment: Oh god, that took me <1 minute to write and still you two got before me!